# Faster way to compare String objects

Tags: java, swing, compare

This is a method i use:

```
public void addSong(LibrarySong song){

    //Check if doublicates exist
    for(int i=0; i<intoPanel.getComponentCount(); i++){  
        if(song.getName().toLowerCase().equals(intoPanel.getComponent(i).getName().toLowerCase()))
            return;
    }

    intoPanel.add(song);    

}
```

.... to insert a new Component to a JPanel.I do this by checking if the name already exists.This works well,but when i have to D&D or insert manually 100.000 items then is running slower and slower.

**My question is:**

Can i use something better to do this process faster?Thanks....

**Edit**:
Following an answer i have changed the code to this:

```
   String name;
   public void addSong(LibrarySong song){

    //Check if doublicates exist
    name=song.getName().toLowerCase();
    for(int i=0; i<intoPanel.getComponentCount(); i++){  
        if(name.equals(intoPanel.getComponent(i).getName().toLowerCase()))
            return;
    }

    intoPanel.add(song);    

}
```

Comment: Why don't you use `Map<String, MyComponent>`

Comment: You can reduce your code a little by using `equalsIgonreCase`.

Comment: @Pshemo I was also thinking about that, but I am not sure if calling `toLowerCase()` once, as StanislavL suggests is actually slower

Comment: @vefthym I didn't say it would be faster, but it will reduce amount of code.

Comment: @Pshemo understood and agreed. I just wonder if it could make the code slower

Comment: @vefthym I would be surprised if it would be noticeable slower since it internally works on similar principles (it is just using upper-case of instead of lower-case).

Comment: Unless I misunderstood you and you ware referring to case where we already have lower-case of one string which will be used everywhere, so we can focus on calculating lower-case of other string instead of both.

Comment: @Pshemo yes, I was referring to the latter, which is mentioned in StanislavL's answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Move the `song.getName().toLowerCase()` before the loop to do `toLowerCase()` once.

UPDATE: Actualy it's not good idea to add 100 000 components. Use e.g JList of JTable to represent the songs with a custom CellRenderer

Comment: @howTo: I think that Stanislav's idea of the JList or JTable is the best idea of the bunch, better than mine actually. 1+. This change will improve your GUI's responsiveness noticeably.

Comment: but JTable doesn't solve O(n^2) problem of removing duplicates. So better to combine both approaches.

Comment: I use and a JTable but i want to have more options for the user.

Comment: @talex it depends. You can define your own TableModel with a TreeSet for names. In this particulr case loop of 100 000 is really fast. The slowest part is strings comparison and **components creation/adding**

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels i hadn't try your idea and you removed it why? i liked it.... also i use both JTable and JPanel on the app so only JTable is not the only solution for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a sorted linked list class to store all your values. Because it is sorted, both insert and search will take O(logN) time, as you can use binary search.

Seems like a lot of work and for practical purposes the HashMap or HashSet are probably better.

Comment: Binary search is quite difficult to use with linked list because it requires index access and linked list suck on it

Answer (score 1):

First of all, don't add 100,000 items to your user interface. For the amount of user interface items you can add to the interface without confusing your users (a few hundred max), the performance of your linear search will be more than sufficient.

If you want to store more than a few hundred songs you will have to think about both your data structures and the user interface.

You can gain much more, both with respect to performance and with respect to user-friendliness, by choosing the right data structures and user interface. For data structure you can use for example a `HashMap<String,LibrarySong>`. Then you can use the following code:

```
if (!song.containsKey(song.getName().toLowerCase()) {
    map.put(song.getName().toLowerCase(), song);
}
```

which almost runs in constant time.

For the user interface it probably best just to let the user enter a name, and then search the corresponding song in your data structure.

Have you considered using a database for your data storage?

Comment: Thanks for reply yes i use SQLITE for dataBase.I am know thinking about the way the interface will be when the items will be tranformed for more than 1000 for example....